# Windows CMD find duplicate files between two disk drives

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, duplicate

I have two drives, let's say driveA (F:) and driveB (G:).
I had once copied all of the contents of driveB into driveA.
But after that the driveB has some new files and folders added to it.
I would like to delete the duplicate files and folders from driveB and leave only those that do not exist in driveA.

I have tried the below command just to check if the duplicates are found but it does not work as I wanted because it has the full path in the variable `%%a`.
Of course, the output that now has `echo %%a` will be replaced with a `DEL`equivalent in case it works.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir G:\*.* /b /s') do if not exist "F:\%%a" echo %%a >> C:\Users\billy\Desktop\files.txt
pause
```

If I remove the `/s` switch from the `dir` command it works because the `%%a` has only the file name instead of the full path but it is not working recursively for the subfolders, so it is not that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('
  dir G:\*.* /b /s /A:-D
  ') do if not exist "F:%%~pnxa" echo del "%%~a" >> C:\Users\billy\Desktop\files.txt
pause
```

Explanation:

- `/A:-D` to exclude directories (folders) from the list as subsequent `del` command would delete files instead of directory (as per `del /?`: If a directory is specified, all files within the directory will be deleted, but the folder itself will not be removed);
- treat folders apart: use another `for /F` against `dir` with `/A:D` switch but in this case use `rd` instead of `del` command to [delete a folder](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html); use `rd /S` to remove an entire folder tree (all files and subfolders in addition to the folder itself).
- `%%~pnxa` expands `%%a` to full [path + name + extension](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) including a leading `\` (no `G:` disk specification);
- `del "%%~a"` double quoted full path to treat paths with spaces properly;
- I recommend `"delims="` instead of `"tokens=*"` to treat possible leading space(s) in file names properly (this could take in place with no `/S` flag);
- consider additional command line switches (see `del /?` and `rd /?`).